# Design: Next privilege content

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Recently I saw new design changes. Overall they look really nice, but I've found that  the content of "Next privilege" doesn't look good:

[image]

Comment: What browser are you looking at this with?

Comment: Mozilla Firefox 54.0

Comment: I see the same on Google Chrome, 59.0.3071.115

Comment: same here on Mozilla Firefox 54.0 32-bit, as well as Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

Comment: Thanks for reporting the bug. I'll take a look.

Comment: btw, for me the popup looks ok, there is a linebreak in the title. Just the progress bar looks bad, see [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/02jO96i.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed and pushed to production. The font-size has been reduced when the privileges progress bar is smaller.

Comment: Great! Although I still see this close button on "d".

Comment: Haha. I forgot to look at that. I'll look into that as well.